# Find and replace using array of keys to find, and array values to replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, replace

I have, in jQuery, written the below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var wordlist = new Array();
    wordlist['BioResource'] = 'Bio Resource is a lorem';

    var array_length = wordlist.length;

    for(var key in wordlist) {
        $("p").html(function(index, value) {

            return value.replace(new RegExp("\b(" + key + ")\b", "gi"), '<a href="#" class="test" title="'+wordlist[key]+'">$1</a>');

        });
    }

});
```

It should (but doesn't), loop through the wordlist array and for each key, try to find that word in any paragraph tags and replace it with itself but wrapped in an anchor with a title tag of the appropriate value of the array at that key.

What am I doing wrong?

The regex itself is working if I remove the array aspect from this and directly input the key and value like this:

```
return value.replace(/\b(BioResource)\b/gi, '<a href="#" class="test" title="'+wordlist['BioResource']+'">$1</a>');
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Paul

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what data you have, and what you want returned? Also, your `wordlist` isn't an `Array`, but an `Object`, if you access it like: `wordlist['BioResource']`. Use `= {};` instead of `= new Array();`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on specifying it as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
"\b(" + key + ")\b"
```

To this:

```
"\\b(" + key + ")\\b"
```

`\b` in string literal represents backspace character. Even if it doesn't have any special meaning, to specify `\` in string, you need to escape it: `\\`. Otherwise, `\` will just vaporize, or a syntax error will be thrown.

Comment: How on earth did you guys answer that so quickly! And explained the solution too! When the time limit is up, you get the points (though @salexch beat you to it) because yours has an explanation).

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it around and replace any word you can find. This way you only iterate over each paragraph text once to perform the actual replacement.

This solution finds all words inside each paragraph, using `(\w+)` and see whether the contents matches in your `wordlist` object. When found it makes the replacement, if not, it will leave that word alone.

```
$('p').html(function(index, old) {
  return old.replace(/(\w+)/g, function($0, $1) {
        return wordlist[$1] || $0;
    });
});
```